# onclick event on radioButton not working

Tags: android, radio-button, onclicklistener

I have a list on which i Want to give on-click event on radio-button of each row in the list.But this code is not working. Giving force close.Please can anyone me help out.I am new to this.

```
 package com.example.radiogroup;


    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.DataSetObserver;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Checkable;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.os.Build;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Checkable
{

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> data;
    private ListAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        data=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        prepareListData();
        adapter = new ListAdapter(this,data);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    /*  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id)
            {

            {
                if(position==0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Move forward", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
            }

        }); */





    }
    private void prepareListData()
    {
        HashMap<String,Object> row1=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        row1.put("ID",1 );
        row1.put("NAME","Taj Mahal");
        data.add(row1);

        HashMap<String,Object> row2=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        row2.put("ID",2 );
        row2.put("NAME","Agra Fort");
        data.add(row2);

        HashMap<String,Object> row3=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        row3.put("ID",3 );
        row3.put("NAME","Ram Baugh");
        data.add(row3);

        HashMap<String,Object> row4=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        row4.put("ID",4 );
        row4.put("NAME","Panch Mahal");
        data.add(row4);

        HashMap<String,Object> row5=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        row5.put("ID",5 );
        row5.put("NAME","Musamman Burj");
        data.add(row5);

    }
    class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> list;
         ViewHolder holder;



         public ListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> list){
                this.context = context;
                this.list = list;
                holder.rb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Move forward", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
         }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {

                if(convertView == null){
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row,null,false);
                    holder.rb = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);

                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                }else{
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                holder.rb.setText(list.get(position).get("NAME").toString());

            return convertView;
        }
         class ViewHolder
            {
                RadioButton rb;
            }

    }
    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




}
```

Comment: place `OnClikListener()` in `getView()`..then it will work..

Comment: first you should read what a radiobutton actually is.You have to implement a radio group first.Then you have to set a click listener within the adapter

Comment: check answer ans remove from adapter conatracter and add it on getview methed on adapter

Comment: @vibhuti lv in your code is list view not radioButton, but you are posting question about radioButton, I think your post is not clear. If you are confused about list view, you can take help from this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html.

Comment: No actually i have taken a listview and inside that i have placed a radiobutton for each row.

Answer (score 0):

USe it on getview Methed on Adapter

```
 holder.rb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Move forward",        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Use it on OnCreate Methed

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id)
    {

    {
        if(position==0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Move forward "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
  else
   if(position==1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Move forward "+position,  
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
    }

});
```

Comment: in last code i also write this but u r not understand but now u r understand

Comment: I am new to this so. One more thing i want to give different event on each row so where should i set the position for it.

Comment: listview is coming are not

Comment: Listview is displayed but onclick event has no effect.

Comment: Can you please tell me onClick event should be given on radioButton or listView exactly??

Comment: in your code there id comment listview click please uncomment and check

Comment: i m asking to u in your activity there is listview and also click event of listview but listview click event is commented so please uncomment of listview click event

Comment: Ya thats what i am saying.I uncommented it and run the program but its not working.

Comment: please remove it lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE); and also create new post ans send code to me on this mail id er.naveen.tamrakar@gmail.com

Comment: ya ok i have mailed please check it.

Answer (score 0):

in constructor of **ListAdapter**  class you have not  initialize ViewHolder object so you cann't access member of that class. 
remove

```
 holder.rb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Move forward", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```

from **ListAdapter** constructor and put it in **getView()** after class and member initialise.

after

```
 if(convertView == null){
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row,null,false);
                holder.rb = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
```

in getView method.