# Custom Listview Single Choice : setChecked() not working

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view

I am working on a Custom list view with a single choice mode. I have followed the below tutorial and successfully achieved it.

[Custom Single Choice ListView](http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-custon-single-choice-lsitview.html)

I have a use case where I want to set a particular item is the list to be checked by default, 
I have tried to do setChecked(true) at the require position in the adapter but it didnt work.
Can anybody help me how to achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8502062/3922207) says:

> Basically, the single-choice ListView expects the widgets you provide it with to implement the Checkable interface.  LinearLayout et al don't. So you need to create a custom layout that inherits LinearLayout (or whatever layout you want to use for your items) and implements the necessary interface.

And from this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7425650/3922207) you can set it by using custom adapter inside your `Activity`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // set the choice mode
    final ListView list = getListView();
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    // custom adapter
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,
            R.id.title, text) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
            if (list.isItemChecked(position)) {
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.checked);
            } else {
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.unchecked);
            }
            return v;
        }
    });
}
```

> However this version has some performance issues - findViewById and setImageResource are relatively time-consuming operations so you should consider using some caching.

Hope it helps for you.