# Android ListView singleChoice choiceMode not working

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to make a simple interface that allows the user to select a single item in a list by tapping and then press a button to remove it. I have the choice mode on the list set to singleChoice but whenever I tap a item it highlights for a brief moment the goes back to normal. Whenever I press the remove button the getSelectedItem and getSelected View return null. Here is the ListView code:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/times"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/time"
    android:layout_above="@+id/every"/>
```

This is the method called on remove, where list is the ListView and adapt is its ArrayAdapter, using an ArrayList.

```
public void remove(View view)
{
    System.out.println(list.getSelectedItem()+"\n"+list.getSelectedView());
    adapt.remove((String)list.getSelectedItem());
}
```

Edit: I am trying to make this app's minimum API level 10 in case that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>List items are not selectable out of the box by design. You can find more about that [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.mx/2008/12/touch-mode.html):</s>

> Imagine a simple application, ApiDemos for example, that shows a list
>   of text items. The user can freely navigate through the list using the
>   trackball and they can also scroll and fling the list using their
>   finger. The issue in this scenario is the selection. If I select an
>   item at the top of the list and then fling the list towards the
>   bottom, what should happen to the selection? Should it remain on the
>   item and scroll off the screen? In this case, what would happen if I
>   then decide to move the selection with the trackball? Or worse, if I
>   press the trackball to act upon the currently selected item, which is
>   not shown on screen anymore. After careful considerations, **we decided
>   to remove the selection altogether**.

To make them selectable, there are 2 options:

1. Use the row item layout `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice`, which renders radio button for each row. 
   With ArrayAdapter, you can use this layout as:

   ```
   listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
                       dataArray));
   ```
2. Use selectors as background. You can refer This post to know how to do that -
   [how to set choice mode single for listview with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413272/how-to-set-choice-mode-single-for-listview-with-images)

Answer (score 1):

These are two issues:

1. "Selected Highlighting" - for this you need to create depending on how you want to highlight the item a drawlable/color selector - with state_activated="true"

example drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/orange" />
   <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/green" />
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

2. Selection in ListView in any choice mode except NONE is actually handled in checked state so to get the current selection you need to getCheckedItemPosition: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemPosition()